# CSV to JSON converter (Grouping by same keys values)

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, request

I'm trying to convert csv format to JSON, I googled I'm not getting the correct way to modify it to get the desired one.

This is my code in python:

```
import csv
import json

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []

    #reading csv (encoding is important)
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        #csv library function
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        #convert each csv row into python dictionary
        for column in csvReader:
            #add this python dictionary to json array
            jsonArray.append(column)

    #convertion
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)

csvFilePath='example.csv'
jsonFilePath='output.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

and this is my csv file format:

[image]

My actual JSON Output:

```
[
    {
        "Area": "IT",
        "Employee": "Carl",        
    },
    {
        "Area": "IT",
        "Employee": "Walter",      
    },
    {
        "Area": "Financial Resources",
        "Employee": "Jennifer",      
    }
]
```

My desired JSON Output:

```
[
    {
        "Area": "IT",
        "Employee": ["Carl","Walter"],
    },
    {
      "Area": "Financial Resources",
      "Employee": ["Jennifer"],
    }
    
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    areas = {}
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for column in csvReader:
            area, employee = column["Area"], column["Employee"] # split values 
            if area in areas:  # add all keys and values to one dictionary
                areas[area].append(employee)
            else:
                areas[area] = [employee]
    # convert dictionary to desired output format.
    jsonArray = [{"Area": k, "Employee": v} for k,v in areas.items()]
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
```

Comment: Do yo know how I can add more fields in the for loop? I'm trying with: 
`jsonArray = [{"Area": k, "Employee": v, "anotherfield": a,} for k,v,a in areas.items()]`
but this is not allowed.

Comment: If you wanted to add extra fields you would want to do it before the list comprehension.... But it also depends on why you are adding more fields... Is this for a whole new csv file? or are you just adding a blank field to be updated at a later time?

Comment: @MauricioReyes  You could only add another field that way if the information was the same for each iteration.                                                                                             
`jsonArray = [{"Area": k, "Employee": v, "anotherfield": "somevalue"} for k, v in areas.items()]`

Comment: Yes, I already added it on comprehension list. I'm creating a file from scratch which going to increase depending the duties (New fields are not important as this main filter) of a web service registry. But the main filter it was the `Area` grouping.

Answer (score 0):

[convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library provides a lot of reduce operations to handle aggregations (*I must confess, I'm the author*):

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# generates an ad-hoc function, which aggregates data
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("Area"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "area": c.item("Area"),
            "employees": c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item("Employee")),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

result = converter(
    Table.from_csv("tmp/in.csv", header=True).into_iter_rows(dict)
)
assert result == [
    {"area": "IT", "employees": ["Carl", "Walter"]},
    {"area": "Financial Resources", "employees": ["Jennifer"]},
]
```